# DataGrid Format Cell property

Tags: vb.net, datagrid

My datagrid is not formatting the input value.

If I input "5", it returns "5" and not "5,00%"

I tried to change the cellstyle format of the cell in editor to "0,00%" or to "P", but it doesn't format... Already tried "000" or "0,00" and nothing happens... It always returns "5"

[image]
[image]

Comment: Maybe the corresponding Column data type is `string` instead of `float` or `double` or...? You can always use the `CellFormatting` event, but setting the correct data type is quite probably better.

Answer (score 1):

If it's any consolation, I couldn't reproduce your complaint:

[image]

I set everything up in code, but only because it makes it easier to paste onto SO. Paste this into a form and have a play around with it:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim dt As New DataTable

    dt.Columns.Add("Thing", GetType(Double))
    dt.Rows.Add(1.234)
    dt.Rows.Add(2.345)

    Dim dg As New DataGridView
    dg.DataSource = dt

    Me.Controls.Add(dg) 'so that columns are autogenerated

    dg.Columns(0).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "0.00\%"

End Sub
```

---

You can do the same in the designer; doesn't have to be code

- Add a New DataSet to your project, add a DataTable to it with a decimal capable column (pick better names than I have here):

[image]

- Open the data sources panel (view menu, other windows), drag the datatable to the form to create a grid, edit the grid's columns to set the format:

[image]

- and put some data in the underlying table:

  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
  Me.DataSet1.DataTable1.AddDataTable1Row(1.234)
  Me.DataSet1.DataTable1.AddDataTable1Row(2.345)
  End Sub

[image]

Comment: Got it... I solved this problem with "CellValueChanged" event... The way you showed to me, I need to create a dataset... With a datagrid, I can't change the column data type... Thanks anyway... Thumbed up

Comment: *I can't change the column data type* yes, that's because datagridviews aren't really supposed to contain data.. You keep your data in something else (a datatable) and you connect a grid to it to *show* it. As a concept it's called ["model, view, controller"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) and it helps keep concerns separate in an application. If you adopt the approach of keeping your data in a datatable rather than putting it directly into the grid, lots of things will start to make a lot more sense! ;)